# python update csv file with condition where column2 startswith column1

Tags: python, pandas

I want to print true in new column3, where column2 starts with column1, else print false in column3

this is my example CSV file

```
column1  column2
foo      footer
one      two
pro      programmer
queue    text
```

I want updated csv file like below

```
column1  column2     column3
foo      footer      true
one      two         false
pro      programmer  true
queue    text        false
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `list comprehension` to check if column1 exists in column 2

```
df['column3'] = [column2.startswith(column1) for column1, column2 in df.to_numpy()]
```

Comment: could also use `apply` `df.apply(lambda x : x['column2'].startswith(x['column1']),axis=1)` wonder if this could be vectorised

Comment: I dont think Pandas can vectorize strings yet; even numpy's ``array`` is not as fast as python's native string processing AFAICT